# Prove my work is not a trade secret violation

Tags: copyright

I have recently developed a medical application. One of my previous employers (from 4 years ago) also sells similar application. (You can see where it is going)

I developed this application from scratch in Silverlight and later moved to WPF. It uses Prism for IoC, Entity framework, MVVM with ViewModel first and RIA based WCF servics.

The application my previous employer sells is based on WinForms. Uses classic 3-tier architecture with Most of the code in form code-behind, a Business layer. a Data access layer that performs CRUD operations using TSQL.

The employer is now alleging that I might have stolen the code and created my own version but that is truly not the case. Every line of code has been written from scratch.

The employer is also alleging trade secret violation (without even looking at the software) but everything this software does is based on public domain knowledge. Managing patients, Exams, Bills etc are all public knowledge. Specific tests that go in each exam have been made based on material read from books that I can prove.

My software simply provides a different way of managing practice that has not borrowed anything from my previous employer's software.

I need to present a detailed comparison of the two technologies so my lawyer can include that in a formal reply.

Anyone has experience going through a similar scenario who can help me write a good comparison?